# What exactly does this statement do?

Tags: mysql, union

The statement

```
SELECT password 
FROM users 
WHERE username='' 
UNION 
SELECT 'test' 
FROM users
```

returns

```
password
--------
test
```

and the statement

```
SELECT username, password 
FROM users 
WHERE username='' 
UNION 
SELECT 'test', 'test' 
FROM users
```

returns

```
username        password
--------        --------
test            test
```

**What exactly is happening here?**

Because if you omit the `WHERE` clause, the first `SELECT` returns all the user rows and the `UNION SELECT` adds on to that the row `test        test`:

```
username        password
--------        --------
johnny          pw123
wiener          peter
test            test
```

I understand that adding the `WHERE username=''` clause returns no rows, so then the `UNION SELECT` adds on to nothing a single row containing `test        test`.

But when you just have the statement `SELECT 'test, 'test' FROM users`, it doesn't return one such row but a row for every user. So multiple rows. You'll have as many rows in the output of this statement as there are users in the users table:

```
username        password
--------        --------
test            test          <- one for johnny
test            test          <- one for wiener
```

So I'm trying to reconcile these behaviors. This `SELECT` above would normally return a row per user, but when it's a `UNION SELECT` adding on to the rows returned by the first `SELECT`, it only returns one row, not one per user. And the first `SELECT` returns nothing unless the `WHERE` clause is omitted in which case it returns all the users rows.

As an add-on to this long question, the `UNION SELECT` adds on `test        test` to the output of, for example

```
username        password
--------        --------
johnny          pw123
wiener          peter
```

So it's natural that they fall under the columns of "username" and "password". But when you have the `WHERE` clause that makes the first `SELECT` return nothing, how is it that the overall statement returns

```
password        username
--------        --------
test            test
```

and not

```
Expr1000        Expr1000
--------        --------
test            test
```

Is it because it's inaccurate to say the `SELECT` returns "nothing" and rather that it returns "no rows under the columns of 'username' and 'password'", meaning that it establishes for the `UNION SELECT` these columns regardless of if the first `SELECT` has any rows under them?

Have I answered my own questions via the Socratic method? Or is my thinking wrong? If I have answered myself, I apologize for wasting five minutes of your time reading 400 words.

Comment: "Better to ask a stupid question than to stay in the dark." or in French "Mieux vaut poser une question stupide que de rester dans l'ignorance." Author:[Strella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strella). Your question is all but stupid above all someone may ask himself the same ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note you should always include what version of the database system you're using as one of the tags in your question, as that's usually relevant.*

What I suspect you're experiencing in your specific case (given your examples are with *test* data) is the de-duplication that's occuring from the [`UNION` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-distinct-all) in MySQL:

> By default, duplicate rows are removed from UNION results. The optional DISTINCT keyword has the same effect but makes it explicit. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.

In your first query, the `WHERE` clause has no matches and therefore the first half of the statement has no rows to return, but your second half of the `UNION` is a hard-coded value that is repeated for every row in the table but then de-duped by the `UNION` operator, resulting in a single row ultimately.

As you noticed, when you directly query the table with the second half of your original statement, you do get a row back with the values `test` repeated for each row in the table. This is because you're no longer using the `UNION` operator which was de-duping your results before.

As specified in the aforementioned quote from the MySQL docs, if you use the `UNION ALL` operator instead, then duplicates won't be removed, and you would receive all rows, as expected, with repeated values of `test`. E.g. `SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='' UNION ALL SELECT 'test' FROM users`

Note this is also common behavior of that operator in most modern relational database systems.

Comment: Also note that the deduplication due to the use of `UNION` almost always implies an extra sort operation on the final data, so unless you expect and need the duplicates `UNION ALL` is usually more efficient especially on large result sets.

Answer (score 2):

> But when you just have the statement SELECT 'test, 'test' FROM users, it doesn't return one such row but a row for every user.

Structured Query Language (SQL) as we know and love it, say ...

```
select thing1, thing2, thing3 
from somewhere
```

... is basically written the *wrong way around*.
To the database, it's more like

```
from somewhere 
select things1, things2, things3
```

It *starts* with the "from" and "where" clauses and works out the "tuple-set" that it needs to construct (the rows, taken from various tables, and mushed together in the way that your query describes) *and* how best to *do* that construction (the Query Plan).
Then, from that "tuple-set", it returns the things that you've asked for.

So, in your case ...

```
SELECT 'test', 'test' 
FROM user
```

... it goes off and creates the tuple-set of every row in the user table and then returns to the two *literals*, 'test' and 'test', that you asked for.

Another classic is when you mistype an on-the-fly query and run something like ...

```
select 8 from users ;
```

.. and get a long, useless list of eights for your trouble.